# AppEngine JDO queries don't fetch objects, if I change the class definition

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a class called User. it looks somethinh like this

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User
{
    @Persistent private String key;
    @Persistent private String email;
    @Persistent private String password;
    ...
}
```

I have some User objects in the datastore. I added two more fields to the definition.

```
@Persistent private boolean passwordReset;
@Persistent private boolean needsReset;
```

Now, my queries on email

```
pm.newQuery(User.class, "email == mail");
query.execute(email);
```

don't return any data, even though the datastore viewer still displays the objects. What can I do to fix it?

edit: more code without jdo:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("User");
q.addFilter("email", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, email);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
Entity result = pq.asSingleEntity();
```

t is null even if there is mathing data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228941/gae-comparing-string-value-returning-false-results-when-executing-jdo-query)). You probably did'nt implement the serialVersionUID field in your class. Eventually I had to create a new JDO object and migrate the existing data (old objects) to the new model using a handler.