# GAE: Comparing String value returning false results when executing JDO query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

For an iOS project I'm using GAE (Java stack) to store the user's device token and use it to send Push notifications.

I have a Device entity which contains several fields, including "appVersion" field of type String. The database contains some Devices with version 1 and some with version 2.

When I run a JDO query to find all devices with "appVersion" equals to 2 it returns the expected result, but when I do the same with version 1 the query return no result, although there are Entities which match this condition.

This is the code:

```
javax.jdo.Query query = _pm.newQuery(Device.class, "appVersion == appVersionParams");

query.declareParameters(String.class.getName()+" appVersionParams");

List<Device> results = (List<Device>) query.execute(message.getAppVersion());
```

I verified several times that the Device Entities with version 1 are stored correctly (the type is String and contains the right, trimmed value which indeed match exactly to the parameter I'm passing).

I first encountered this issue on the Dev environment, so I deleted the local DB and created test entities and run the Query again - this time it returned the expected results for version 1 and 2. But after I restarted the server it again returned false results for version 1 (while doing good with version 2). Hoping it was just a bug on the local dev env. I deployed it to the production environment and it returned only 4 entities (there are few thousands match this condition) - all entities were stored in the same way/API.

I also tried to switch from JDO to the low level APIs to fetch the Entities but i got the same weird behavior. This is the code for it:

```
Query q = new Query("Device");
q.addFilter("appVersion", FilterOperator.EQUAL, message.getAppVersion());
```

I'm going nuts here.. what's going on ??

Comment: Try with `this.appVersion` in the query.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it locally and also deployed it to GAE but the results are the same. I got only few entities back when i'm expecting thousands.

Comment: Are you sure you are persisting them correctly? I mean, if you don't filter then do you get them all as expected?

Comment: yes, I verified it both on the dev & productive env.: when i remove the filter i get all Entities. Is there a way to debug the query in some way?

Comment: You might try a GQL query in the admin console data viewer as a sanity check. e.g. if version is a number: SELECT * FROM Device where appVersion = 1 ; or if version is a string: SELECT * FROM Device where appVersion = '1'

Comment: I tried and it get even more strange: when I run it with appVersion = '1' I get few result back. And when executing with appVersion != '1' AND appVersion != '2' I get the thousands of devices with version 1 which were missing on the first run. Im starting to think it relates to the fact that in some point I added another persistent property to the Device entity and only the ones which were newly created with this property are the ones that are responding correctly to the query. Is there an upgrade procedure I should follow when adding properties/fields for persistent objects?

Comment: Yes: you shouldn't. If you change the class of the objects JDO is going to get **very** confused, even more so if you don't specify correctly different `serialVersionUID`s when modifying.

Comment: I'm guessing this is it (i did not use serialVersionUID). I will try to run a task to iterate all the "old" objects and save it again. If it will solve the problem then I'll know for sure the problem was with the update.

Comment: This was it! I tried to re-save all entities filling the missing property but it wasn't good enough - so eventually i created new entity with the same properties and named it differently (UserDevice). Then I copied all Device entities to new UserDevice entities. Now the query on UserDevice works as expected! GAE docs do not include even a clue about this.. I hope this question will help anyone else who encounter the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a modification I made to the persistent Entity structure/schema without proper use of `serialVersionUID`. See the question's comments for more details, specifically Viruzzo's one.